# Import multiple ranges to a single sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, importrange

I have two different sheets, with two of the same ranges (age). I want to combine these two separate ranges into one on a different sheet. Current formula / function I am using:

```
={(importrange("https...", "Sheet1!A2:A100"));(importrange(""https...", "Sheet2!A2:A100"))}"))
```

What am I doing wrong?

I was able to bring in one range at a time with this formula / function:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https...", "Sheet1!A2:A100")
=IMPORTRANGE("https...", "Sheet2!A2:A100")
```

but I need them to be in one column together (the order does not matter, I just need the values to be pulled across).

Comment: @Jeeped Thank you so much! 

For some reason this did not work. The second range does not add. 

Please have a look at this Google Sheets Doc

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JvCJgcm2H-QsOv2p9JX4ZtjR4sH5tQGZdpuTbr39qsE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Take a look at the revised formula in 'Destination 2 - Trying again'!B2 on https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JvCJgcm2H-QsOv2p9JX4ZtjR4sH5tQGZdpuTbr39qsE/edit#gid=1048764896.

Answer (score 3):

Try two IMPORTRANGE functions within one formula separated by a semi-colon and wrapped in braces (e.g. { and } that you type yourself)

```
={IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mYWnO8vzyb5o4jzp-Ti-369nSyQoCfg-WzqaaTb94tE", "Sheet1!A2:A10");IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mYWnO8vzyb5o4jzp-Ti-369nSyQoCfg-WzqaaTb94tE", "Sheet2!A2:A")}
```

If you do not have a set number of rows in the source sheet1 (e.g. A2:A100), then the retrieved data from sheet2 will start on the 101st row with blanks above it. To get around this, concatenate a dynamic 'last populated' row number onto the range string.

```
={IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mYWnO8vzyb5o4jzp-Ti-369nSyQoCfg-WzqaaTb94tE", "Sheet1!A2:A"&match(1E+99, IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mYWnO8vzyb5o4jzp-Ti-369nSyQoCfg-WzqaaTb94tE", "Sheet1!A:A")));IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mYWnO8vzyb5o4jzp-Ti-369nSyQoCfg-WzqaaTb94tE", "Sheet2!A2:A")}
```

[source link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mYWnO8vzyb5o4jzp-Ti-369nSyQoCfg-WzqaaTb94tE/edit?usp=sharing)

[destination link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16_7qi4l-2gmmGiVBLkDuuwofFhhJJmaDsPcYyYMXcwM/edit?usp=sharing)

[image] [image] [image]

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

You have a couple of double inverted commas too many and unmatched parentheses (also some unnecessary spaces and parentheses). Following should work, with granting authorisation if required.:

```
={importrange(" k e y 1 ","Sheet1!A2:A100");importrange(" k e y 2 ","Sheet2!A2:A100")}
```

It might help to compare 'yours' and 'mine' in a word processor and fixed width font.